# Use aliases in a query condition syntax?

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if is possible use a `aliases` in a `where` condition.

For exemple this:

```
SELECT name AS NAMESS, age from user AS MEN where MEN.name LIKE '%Cortan%';
```

Trying to look like this:

```
SELECT name AS NAMESS, age from user AS MEN where MEN.NAMESS LIKE '%Cortan%';
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: No. The "Where" statement is evaluated before select statement and the aliases.

Comment: SO post with a solution using a temp table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664657/column-alias-in-a-where-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The cited duplicate was not quite a duplicate, because it is not specific for MySQL.)

The answer to your question is that you can never use:

```
SELECT name AS NAMESS, age
from user AS MEN
where MEN.NAMESS LIKE '%Cortan%';
```

unless `NAMESS` is a column in `user`.  You could do a subquery:

```
SELECT NAMESS, age
from (SELECT u.*, u.name as NAMESS FROM user u) MEN
where MEN.NAMESS LIKE '%Cortan%';
```

And this would work.

You can remove the `MEN.` qualification and use a `HAVING` clause (this is a MySQL extension):

```
SELECT name AS NAMESS, age
FROM user MEN
HAVING NAMESS LIKE '%Cortan%';
```

Or, you can do what countless others do, and simply refer to the column/expression before the alias:

```
SELECT name AS NAMESS, age
FROM user MEN
WHERE MEN.names LIKE '%Cortan%';
```

The `MEN.` is optional, but if you have multiple tables, qualified column names are highly recommended.